# How to dim an LED with a 10 k potentiometer?

Tags: led, potentiometer, dimmer

I would like to know how to use a 10 k potentiometer with a small LED. Each time I try, the LED won't turn off completely and also it used only 20% of the potentiometer. I would like to be able to used the full potentiometer range, from LED off to fully bright .

I've used an NE555 circuit  and still have problems.

[image: NE555 led dimmer circuit]

Comment: What is the maximum current that you want to go through the LED?

Comment: Show us the circuit you've used.

Comment: Is this school work?

Comment: Leads will run at very low currents. Sticking a 10k resistor in will dim it, but that's all.

Comment: Yes it's a scholle project for my daughter, i have included the circuit ...

Comment: With the current circuit I can't see what's stopping the LED from burning when the mosfet is on.

Comment: @Colin: There's a varistor in that circuit near the left in a loop with two diodes between pinks 6 and 7 of the IC.

Comment: @BenVoigt: that's a potentiometer, not a varistor.  It will vary the duty cycle driving the LED, but you still need a resistor in series with the LED to limit the maximum current through it.

Comment: There's a resistor for the led ( not on the drawing ) but the led won't go completely off when potentiometer is turn off,,,how can i fix that ?

Comment: @PeterBennett: Sorry yes I meant variable resistor.

Comment: You can get a potentiometer with a switch built in to make sure the LED/circuit really is off, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

The way that circuit works is that it pulses the LED on and off, the brightness is controlled by the ratio of time on to time off. That circuit will give you a minimum of around 10% on time, so the LED will never go completely off.

It will on the other hand, go to nearly a 100% duty cycle. So what you could try is to invert the output of the 555 before it goes to the MOSFET, a simple NPN transistor inverter should do it. That way instead of the adjustment going from something like 99.9% on to 10% on, it will go from 90% on to 0.1% on. That should probably be enough that the LED won't appear to be on at the minimum setting.

Here are three images from a simulation showing the LED current with the pot at maximum, midpoint and minimum.

[image: LED dimmer at max pot setting]

[image: LED dimmer at mid pot setting]

[image: LED dimmer at min pot setting]

Comment: Thank you very much!   It work fine now !